# Missing favicon in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, seo, favicon

I have a new website (few weeks old), which is published and using index/follow rules ... everything seems good, and indexed correctly, all SEO attributes seems correctly. ..

BUT

In google search console and also in search results in google, favicon is missing. I have correctly placed webmanifest:

```
{
    "theme_color": "#007FFF",
    "background_color": "#000000",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "start_url": "https://bestdosgames.com",
    "name": "bestDOSgames.com",
    "short_name": "bestDOSgames.com",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-36x36.png",
            "sizes": "36x36",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "0.75"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-48x48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "1.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-72x72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "1.5"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-96x96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "2.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "3.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "4.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icon-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "4.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icon-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "4.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "density": "4.0",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also in header I have:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest"/>
```

What am I missing? Site url is https://bestdosgames.com, so you can take a look at...

All icons are publicly available. I'm using Next 13 with App folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your favicon file in the top level of your app/ directory. The favicon file should be of .ico type.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the documentation:

```
Use an image file to set an app icon by placing a `favicon`, `icon`, or `apple-icon` image file within your `/app` directory.
The `favicon` image can only be located in the top level of `app/`.

Next.js will evaluate the file and automatically add the appropriate tags to your app's `<head>` element.

| File convention             | Supported file types                    | Valid locations |
| --------------------------- | --------------------------------------- | --------------- |
| [`favicon`](#favicon)       | `.ico`                                  | `app/`          |
| [`icon`](#icon)             | `.ico`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.svg` | `app/**/*`      |
| [`apple-icon`](#apple-icon) | `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`                 | `app/**/*`      |
```